# How long will it take to create an OS backup image?

Tags: windows-7, backup

How much time will it take to backup **49GB**? Here are the details:

- Windows 7
- Dual core CPU 2.50 GHz
- 2GB memory

I'll use the free version of Macrium Reflect. I will back it up to a Seagate portable hard-drive. I have installed: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, NetBeans, and some CS4 Master Collection products. I only need to backup one partition.

Answer (score 2):

Average Write speed with Compression would be 300MB/Min, calculate :)

Comment: 300MB/min = 5MB/sec? That seems pretty slow to me. I would think 20-50MB/sec (1200-3000MB/min) would be more correct. But I've never used 'macrium reflect' before, so it might be slow.

Comment: Yes, You need to calculate the time for COmpression.. I guess it would be around 300-450 MB/m